# Warning: Variable is shadowed in inline assembly by an instruction of the same name

Tags: solidity

I'm facing this warning on one of our solidity scripts
(compiler version - 0.4.18), this is a snippet on which I receive the warning

`function () external payable onlyDuringSale isInitialized {
  create(msg.sender);
}`

`function create(address _recipient) public payable onlyDuringSale isInitialized {....}`

Changing the function name to `Create` resolves the warning.

Can someone please explain why?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the complete warning message. The compiler usually tells you exactly where the shadowed declaration is. browser/Untitled4.sol:13:24: Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration.
    function something(uint _variable) private {
                       ^------------^
browser/Untitled4.sol:8:5: The shadowed declaration is here:
    uint _variable;
    ^------------^

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm very late to answer the question, but for anyone else having this issue:
The problem here is that `create` is an assembly instruction (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/assembly.html)

So your solution of renaming the function is the only valid one in this case